# In componentDidMount offsetWidth of the element is incorrect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I use `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` to track some changes and resize elements. But sometimes in `componentDidMount` element width is not correct, it is different from the real size, which I see later in the DOM. And I cannot get the case when debugging.

Comment: Any code ? Are you setting the state in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: I am just getting widths of some elements and set their sum as a left property for another element.